# Date range [list box to datagrid view]

Tags: vb.net

**My code is working in list box But I don't save it in access data grid view table. Below is my coding. Please give me a solution.**

```
Private Sub btnRange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRange.Click

    Dim firstDate As Date
    Dim secDate As Date

    firstDate = DateTimePicker1.Text
    secDate = DateTimePicker2.Text

    If firstDate = secDate Then

    ElseIf firstDate > secDate Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date range")

    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(firstDate)
        Do Until firstDate = secDate
            firstDate = firstDate.AddDays(1)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(firstDate)
        Loop
    End If

End Sub
```

[image: My Date range project Picture]

Comment: You want the same data that appears in the list box to appear in the second column of the DataGridView?

Comment: Mary, I want the same data that appears in the list box to appear in the second column of the DataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the Rows.Add with the values you want to insert in the grid.

```
Private Sub FillGridWithDates()


 'Set up the grid columns - you may already have done this at design time
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "si"
        DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Date"

        Dim firstDate As Date
        Dim secDate As Date
        'The text property is a string, the Value property is a date
        firstDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
        secDate = DateTimePicker2.Value

        If firstDate = secDate Then
            'Do something here
        ElseIf firstDate > secDate Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date range")
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(firstDate)
            'I just assumed a value for si
            Dim si As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(si, firstDate)
            Do Until firstDate = secDate
                firstDate = firstDate.AddDays(1)
                ListBox1.Items.Add(firstDate)
                si = ListBox1.Items.Count
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(si, firstDate)
            Loop
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Mary, thanks for your help. But which data shown by DataGridView1 I want to save them in my Access Table. Please help me.

Comment: Mary, When I changed Datagridview1 to Table1datagridview which is my Access Table and run this form Then error message show. An error message is "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound." Please, help me How can I save DatagridView1 showed data in my Access Table.

Comment: The picture of your datagridview was empty so I didn't realize it was a bound control. Please post the code where it is bound as part of your question. Saving the data to an Access database would be a new question.

Comment: Mary, Yes this is new question.your previous code is work nicely in Datagridview1. I change my Datagridview to table1datagridview which is my Access default table. and then when i click display range button then new problem come in coding. I post the code where it is bound and give me solution Please.  **Table1DataGridView.Rows.Add(sl, firstDate)**

Comment: `Dim sl As Integer = Table1DataGridView.Rows.Count
            Table1DataGridView.Rows.Add(sl, firstDate)
            Do Until firstDate = secDate
                firstDate = firstDate.AddDays(1)
                sl = Table1DataGridView.Rows.Count
                Table1DataGridView.Rows.Add(sl, firstDate)
            Loop`

Comment: I meant post a new question.